# Unable to grant Opportunity Team - Read Only Access

Tags: permissions, opportunity-teams

Scenario: We have enabled Opportunity Team and I have added some users in Team Member. Earlier all the Team Members had Read/Write Access. Now I wanted to change the Access Permission of some users to Read Only, But its not changing to Read Only.
I tried changing the Opportunity OWD to Read Only, then I am able to grant Read Only Access to all. Condition is like say Account Manager & Sales Manager can have Read/Write but others like Sales Rep & Channel Manager should have Read Only.

I am Unable to do this.

Please advise, Am I missing something?

Comment: What was previous OWD? One thing to note is that : the member’s opportunity access level can’t be less than your Salesforce org’s default opportunity sharing access.

Comment: Earlier it was Read/Write now changed to Read Only. If it cannot be less than OWD access level & I am setting it to Read Only so i thought it should work.

Comment: So that's it. OWD was read/write and you are trying to give opp team members read only access. Yo can't restrict sharing access granted via OWD.

Comment: Then If I keep Read Only, I should be able to give Read/Write. If so then Read/Write Option doesnt comes up in Team member